# login check with python Dictionary

Tags: python, authentication

guys anyone help me with the checking solution which is as follows:

```
# class mates
#small database with a Dic
c_m = {
'lod':123,
'ele':345,
'ali':456,
'abq':567,
'amr':678
}

login = input("please enter user name: ")
password = input("please enter {} password ".format(login))
```

i need to check if the login key is exist in the Dic if yes check if the password match the value of the key in the Dic if yes Pass else Pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c_m = {
'lod':123,
'ele':345,
'ali':456,
'abq':567,
'amr':678
}

login = input("please enter user name: ")
password = input("please enter {} password ".format(login))

if login in c_m and c_m[login] == int(password):
    print("good")
else:
    print("bad")
```

Also, i would suggest that you get the pass this way.

```
from getpass import getpass
password = getpass()
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can check if a key exists simply with the 'in' keyword.

```
if login in c_m: # checks if the key exists
    if c_m[login] == password:
        #--correct authentication action here
else:
    #--incorrect auth
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# class mates
#small database with a Dic
c_m = {
    'lod':123,
    'ele':345,
    'ali':456,
    'abq':567,
    'amr':678
}

login = input("please enter user name: ")
password = input("please enter {} password ".format(login))

expected_password = c_m.get(login, None)

if expected_password == password:
    # password was correct
else:
    # incorrect password
```

you can use `dict.get("key", default_value)`

this will return the password for what ever key you enter, but if a key is not in the dictionary you can return the default. In this case I put None as a default and compared the password to that. This isn't 100% failsafe as I'm sure there are conditions where input can return None.

Comment: can you explain what .get(   ,None) means i am a beginner

Comment: Sure, Sorry for the late response, but essentially if that key doesn't exist inside of the dictionary, it will return None by default, otherwise you will get the value associated with the key.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for remind me the solution was as follows:

```
c_m = {
'lod':123,
'ele':345,
'ali':456,
'abq':567,
'amr':678
```

}

```
login = input("please enter user name: ")
password = input("please enter {} password ".format(login))
pass2= int(password)
```

if login in c_m and c_m[login] == pass2 :
       print('Welcome {}'.format(login))

```
elif login in c_m and c_m[login] != pass2:
   print("{} please Check you Password".format(login))
```

else:
       print('Somthing went Wrong!')